# How do I get the internet to work?

Tags: wireless, lubuntu

I know this might be a bit of a duplicate but I cant figure it out, I'm running Lubuntu and im completely new to stuff like this, I can connect but I can't use it, and when I try to use the commands people suggest they arent found, when I try to download them it fails. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably you should be more specific and tell exactly which commands you issued that did not work. Only then we can help you.

Comment: if you can connect (ie. your wireles icon connects) your problem is with your router.

Comment: oh and make sure your ISP does not have a problem. Dutch Ziggo had a massive outage today.

Comment: @Rinzwind my isp shouldnt be having issues since everything else can connect just fine

Comment: @PerlDuck things like Ifconfig and sudo commands,                    i tried "sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf" and that didnt work, most of the imputs i try dont seem to fix it

Comment: @Joker_n_HarleyQ That's still too unspecific. Please edit your question, and add (properly formatted as code) what commands you used, and what the **exact** output was (copy&paste). Else all help you will get is guessing. BTW, this would be a good moment to take the [tour] and read [ask] to learn how you can improve your question.

Comment: What are the results of basic troubleshooting, for example `ping your.router.ip.address` , `ping 8.8.8.8` etc? Have you checked to make sure the interface is up? `ethtool eth0` for example, if your interface is named eth0, should show "Link detected: yes" on the last line for the interface details. If you can ping by IP, but not resolve anything, that is a DNS issue and you will need to make sure your interface has proper DNS settings assigned. Also check whether your interface settings are correct (link speed, etc). Perhaps the interface is set to manual, so you aren't receiving DNS via DHCP?

Comment: @ChrisWoods  when i try to ping it gives me Network is unreachable, where would i go to check the interfece settings?

Comment: @Joker_n_HarleyQ go to Preferences menu and open Network Connections. You should also see it in the tray, left-click to open. The terminal method can be useful to learn: open a terminal window, then type `ifconfig`. On the left hand side, look for the interface which seems appropriate (on one of my Ubuntu VMs, it's `eno1`, on others it can be `eth0`, `ens192` etc). Type `sudo ifconfig <interface> up`, where <interface> is the name you just found. Then try pinging 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1 again. If you have a connection, type `sudo dhclient` and after a few seconds try `ping google.com`.

Comment: @Joker_n_HarleyQ these are also quite useful references: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Networking & https://wiki.gnome.org/DarrenAlbers/NetworkManagerFAQ :-) Lubuntu uses the Ubuntu network management design, so the documentation is common between Ub and Lub. I've been assuming you're using wired ethernet, but are you using a Wi-Fi adapter? If so you'll need to additionally join it to the wireless network, Network Manager can accomplish that more easily than on the commandline if you're a Ubuntu newbie. :-)

Comment: Have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) first, then [edit] your question.  Please avoid asking the same question twice.